# How to create .lisp files and run them on mac?

Tags: macos, terminal, clisp

[As can be seen on the picture TextEdit on mac gives only limited options of file extensions in which I can safe a file. Lisp not included.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQcr4.png)

1. Create .lisp files
   https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lisp/lisp_environment.htm is describing everything step by step, but it says TextEditor on Mac can save .lisp files, which I wasn't able to do.
2. Load .lisp file
   (load "filename.lisp") leads to error: file with such name doesn't exist

Comment: Apple's TextEdit can save Lisp files with extensions .lisp .

Comment: Dariya, in general a text editor is agnostic w/r to the file extension, so I'm lead to think that you are making some sort of mistake — but your description of the problem (_"I wasn't able to do"_) is too skinny to let me guess what went the wrong way and help you... To edit your question and add the relevant info you have to click the `edit` button below your question.

Comment: @RainerJoswig it doesn't. I suppose one can download something, but as it is TextEdit allows to save with extensions from the given list only.

Comment: @ninjaknight: it does. Make the document raw text and save it. The save dialog allows you to name it as foo.lisp and it will be saved as such. Don't save formatted text. See the Textedit preferences menu and the Format menu.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1. TextEditor on mac has limitations to how file can be saved (.txt, etc.). You can use any other editor, ex: **TextWrangler**, which allow you to write file extension. Or you can use editors specific for lisp, ex: Emacs (more massive)
2. It's possible that when you type (load "filename.lisp") it searches in some specific directory, where it's not present. So, to avoid this, you should type **full path** to the file you want to open. Ex: **(load "/Users/macbook/Desktop/foldername/filename.lisp")**

Comment: Textedit has no such limitations. You have choose the correct text format, then you can save raw text with any extension you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty easy to do.

1. Open **TextEdit**.
2. Write your code.
3. Save it as text file or whatever.
4. Go to Finder and find where you saved your file.
5. Right click on the file.
6. Tap to **show information** button.
7. You will notice “Name and Extension” field.
8. Change “.txt” with “.lisp” extension for your file.
9. You are good to go!